# CMake - unable to set source file properties for VS2015

Tags: cmake

I have a simple CMakeLists for my shader code which currently just looks like this -

```
target_sources( JonsEngine
    PRIVATE
        AmbientPixel.hlsl
        AvgLuminance.hlsl
        BoxBlurPixel.hlsl
        Common.hlsl
        Constants.h
        DepthReadback.hlsl
        DirectionalLightPixel.hlsl
        DirectionalLightPCF2X2Pixel.hlsl
        DirectionalLightPCF3X3Pixel.hlsl
        DirectionalLightPCF5X5Pixel.hlsl
        DirectionalLightPCF7X7Pixel.hlsl
        FullscreenTriangle.hlsl
        FullscreenTriangleTexcoord.hlsl
        FXAA.hlsl
        FXAAPixel.hlsl
        GBufferPixel.hlsl
        GBufferVertex.hlsl
        GBufferVertexAnimated.hlsl
        GBufferVertexStatic.hlsl
        OptimizedPCF.hlsl
        PointLightPixel.hlsl
        SDSMFinalCompute.hlsl
        SDSMInitialCompute.hlsl
        SimpleColorPixel.hlsl
        SimpleTexturePixel.hlsl
        SkyboxPixel.hlsl
        SkyboxVertex.hlsl
        SSAOPixel.hlsl
        TerrainDomain.hlsl
        TerrainHull.hlsl
        TerrainPixel.hlsl
        TerrainPixelDebug.hlsl
        Tonemapping.hlsl
        TransformAnimatedVertex.hlsl
        TransformStaticInstancedVertex.hlsl
        TransformStaticVertex.hlsl
)
```

I am trying to add a bunch of compile flags to *some* of them using like -

```
set_source_files_properties( AmbientPixel.hlsl PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/E\"ps_main\" /ps\"_5_0\"" )
```

However when I generate the solution via CMake it seems to ignore this when I look at the compile options for that source file. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: CMake 3.14+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake treats HLSL files as source extra, as it is not a first class language in CMake. [Others](https://cmake-developers.cmake.narkive.com/hyDXgA3T/setting-additional-compile-flags-to-hlsl-files) have had your issue as well, which prompted CMake to add the [VS_SHADER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/VS_SHADER_FLAGS.html) option.

Try something like this instead:

```
add_executable(JonsEngine)

# Set HLSL source file properties with VS_SHADER_FLAGS.
set_source_files_properties( AmbientPixel.hlsl PROPERTIES VS_SHADER_FLAGS "/E\"ps_main\" /ps\"_5_0\"")

# Associate these source extras with the executable defined above.
target_sources(JonsEngine PRIVATE 
    AmbientPixel.hlsl
    AvgLuminance.hlsl
    #
    #  ... other code files here ...
    #
)
```

There are several other shader options CMake created for the Visual Studio generator, such as `VS_SHADER_TYPE` and `VS_SHADER_ENTRYPOINT` which provide additional build information to the shader compiler.

Comment: Tried that, did not work, the shader still dosn't have those properties =/

Comment: Maybe it does not work in combination with `target_sources`...?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan The examples I have seen do not use `target_sources`, they include the `.hlsl` files with the rest of the source files (`.cpp` and `.h` files) provided to the `add_executable` command.

Comment: Tried it and for some wierd reason it dosn't work with `target_sources` but does with the old way... sigh

Comment: @KaiserJohaan That's interesting, but perhaps `target_sources` treats *source extra* files (such as shader files) differently. Regardless, it may be worth submitting a bug report to CMake.

Comment: @KaiserJohaan Just tested on my Windows 10 machine using CMake 3.14.2 and VS 2017. I expanded my answer to show the surrounding CMake commands and their ordering. This allowed me to apply the source file properties to the `AmbientPixel.hlsl` file.